# How to create a document with a customized Page Size using apache poi?

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-poi

Is it possible to create a word document with a customized Page Size like Legal or A4 using apache poi? What I only encountered is getting the page size of a document. But how about creating a word document and saving it? I tried to set the page size using CTSectPr and CTPageSz but when I write the document, the page size is not set. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: "but when I write the document, the page size is not set." How do you have checked this? Have you looked at the `/word/document.xml` in the `*.docx` ZIP package and compared this with a `*.docx` which was created from `Word` and had set the page size? What differences have you found?

Comment: My bad. What I mean is after saving the document and opened it, it is not set in a customized page size

Comment: That I thought. But since you are using the low level part of `apache poi` you needs to be familiar with the internals of the `*.docx` document structure. A `*.docx`  is nothing else than a ZIP archive containing XML files. Create a `*.docx` document with the needed settings using `Word` and then unzip both, the  `*.docx` which was created by `Word` and the one which was created by `apache poi` and compare the content of `/word/document.xml`.

Comment: where can I find the .doxz zip archive and the content /word/document.xml? Thanks

Comment: The `*.docx` file **is** a ZIP archive. My ZIP unpacking software is able simply opening the `*.docx` file as a ZIP archive. Dependent on your ZIP unpacking software maybe you needs renaming the `*.docx` file to `*.zip`.